# How To Log Changes to Session PHP

Tags: php, session

I'm getting the strangest behavior in my application.

When a customer adds an item to their cart it's serialized and entered in their current session.

This works perfectly until I hit one specific page, the checkout page. I've checked every area of the app where the cart is edited, or the session is updated in reference to the cart, and it's just not there.

My session object holds the session in a public data variable then is updated like so:

```
$this->session->data[$key] = $value;
```

I can literally watch the session file in the storage directory change, but I can't figure out a way to backtrace where it's being changed from.

Is there a way I can monitor session changes, or somehow backtrace where this change is coming from?

Comment: It looks like you have you own custom session configuration, why not log out activities in your open/read/write.close session handler methods (i.e. open/close, read/write, gc/destroy)?  Logging within these methods would be no different than logging anywhere else in your application.

Comment: Implement your own [Session Handler](http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php).

Comment: Are you using an MVC framework, CodeIgniter perhaps?

Comment: The [session_trace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apd-set-session-trace.php) might be useful

Comment: Ok ... so I've built a session handler and moved my sessions to the database for testing.  Now how do I capture what class/method is resetting my session?  I tried `debug_backtrace()` but it doesn't seem to work inside the session` write` callback.